# Question about factorial function

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, factorial

Show that $$n!=1+\left(1−{1 \over 1!}\right)n+\left(1−{1 \over 1!}+ {1 \over 2!}\right)n(n−1)+\cdots$$ I can't figure out how this can be solved . I tried to use binomial theorem but I couldn't prove it . I think that it can be solved using the gamma function but it's not immediately obvious

Comment: I just noticed that this question was [asked 5 hours ago](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/829340/simple-factorial-function-question), where it was given an incomplete answer.